# Cannot access cookies from JavaScript but visible on HTTP header

Tags: javascript, cookies, http-headers

I want to access the cookies in a web app I am developing through Javascript. From what I know the JS way is through `document.cookie`

But this function only returns a blank string. However, from the Network Tab in Chrome Developer Tools I can see the cookie data in HTTP Request Header section.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

It's `document.cookie` not `document.cookies`

Comment: Yes I accidentally said cookies... I am using `document.cookie`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
  var cookie = document.cookie;
  var cookieArray = cookie.split('; ');

    // Parse the cookies: get the stored cookie variable
    for(var loop=0; loop < cookieArray.length; loop++)
    {
        var nameValue = cookieArray[loop].split('=');
        // Get the cookie 
        if( nameValue[0].toString() == 'YourCookieName' )
        {
            var Mycookie =  nameValue[1] ;
            alert(Mycookie);

        }
    }
```

Comment: But I said that `document.cookie` returns "" (empty string)